# User-ID comment section of my app is retrieving Fire-base storage link which covers everywhere and Image of the commentator isn't displaying

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Here below is the activity for posting the comment which includes the codes for publishing it to the emulator I can't seem to find or figure out and how where the commentator userID and image refused to be properly retrieved from my firebase Database storage online cloud I really need help on these, stuck and confused.

```
     [@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_details);
            //Setting the status bar to be transparent
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

            // THis code hides the action bar you can always come back here to disable it.
            getSupportActionBar().hide();

            RvComments = findViewById(R.id.rv_comment);
            imagePost = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_Img);
            imageUserPost = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_user_img);
            imageCurrentUser = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_currentUser_img);

            txtPostTittle = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_tittle);
            txtPostDesc = findViewById(R.id.post_details_desc);
            txtPostDataName = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_date_name);

            editTextComment = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_comment);

            btnAddComment = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_add_comment_btn);

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

            // This code is to monitor specific user ID likes


            // add the comment
            btnAddComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    DatabaseReference commentReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(COMMENT_KEY ).child(PostKey).push();
                    String comment_content = editTextComment.getText().toString();
                    String uID = firebaseUser.getUid();
                    String uNAME = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
                    String uIMG = firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                    Comments comments = new Comments(comment_content,uID,uIMG,uNAME);

                    commentReference.setValue(comments).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            showMessage("Comment added");
                            editTextComment.setText("");
                            btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            showMessage("Failed to add comment : "+ e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });


                }
            });


            //Bind all the data to into this view, then send post detail data
            //To postAdapter activity

            String postImage = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postImage");
            Glide.with(this).load(postImage).into(imagePost);

            String postTittle = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tittle");
            txtPostTittle.setText(postTittle);

            String postUserImage = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userPhoto");
            Glide.with(this).load(postUserImage).into(imageUserPost);

            String postDescription = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
            txtPostDesc.setText(postDescription);

            //Make the comment user Image
            Glide.with(this).load(firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(imageCurrentUser);


            //getting the post ID
            PostKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "postKey");
            String date = timestampToString(getIntent().getExtras().getLong("postDate"));
            txtPostDataName.setText(date);
    // Piece of code here retrieves the post from the data base
            initializeRVComments();
        }

        private void  initializeRVComments() {

            RvComments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

            DatabaseReference commentsDBRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(COMMENT_KEY).child(PostKey);
            commentsDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    listComment = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                          Comments comment = snap.getValue(Comments.class);
                        listComment.add(comment);
                    }
                    commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listComment);
                    RvComments.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }



**This is the XML for the comments section**




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#CEE3B6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_user_img"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#373131"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/comment_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/comment_user_img"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/text_comment_goes_here"
            android:textColor="#373131"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/comment_user_img"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/comment_username" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/comment_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/_4_00"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/comment_username"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />][1]


enter image description here.stack.imgur.com/WFHAj.png
```

Answer (score 0):

After a full day checking and running through the whole codes I found out the issue was from my Models constructors, setters and getters lots of things I accidentally interchanged and that caused the whole issue.
PS if you have this kind of issues please do well to observe your constructors, setters and getters there could be problems over there.